# Using CC Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported image in a book

Tags: creative-commons, derivative-works, cc-by-sa

I would like to use an image in the cover page of a paid book.
The image is first published in Wikimedia and it is *licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license*.

I would like to self-publish the book. Should I change the license of the whole book to the same as the image or just put an attribution to the image in a credit page?

Answer (score 1):

> The image is first published in Wikimedia and it is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license.

You should IMHO put the image in the credits and add the CC notice to your book and provide a link to a place you control where the (possibly modified) image is available too in a proper modifiable format.
This may go above and beyond some of the CC requirements but that should cover it.

From the [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) text:

> This Section 4(a) applies to the Work as incorporated in a Collection, but this does not require the Collection apart from the Work itself to be made subject to the terms of this License.

I would consider your book to be a collection of your work + 
that image.

My take is that the Share Alike clause only applies to to that image, not your book as a whole. But I am not a lawyer!